# Adding FontAwesome to style amp-custom

Tags: font-awesome, amp-html, amp-story, amp-access

I am trying to put the source code for FontAwesome:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
```

in  section under tag:

```
<style amp-custom>
...
</style>
```

in order to be fine with AMP standards and not getting errors in Google validations.

My current code is

```
<style amp-custom>
@font-face {
font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
src: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css);}
body { font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";content="";}

</style>
```

However, still I cannot see my FontAwesome icons. Can you help me with correcting the code? Not sure what is wrong for the newest version of FontAwesome.

Thank you for help.
Jakub

Answer (score 1):

You don't need @font-face in your CSS.

It has to work just by adding FontAwesome CSS file in head:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com">
</head>
```

And then you can use it in your HTML like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-bomb" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
The problem is Google Search Console throws validation error for AMP once we put "href" in AMP Header of website:
_The 'href' attribute in the 'link rel=stylesheet for fonts' tag is set to an invalid value 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font_

I need to add fontawesome icons (arrows) before <li> tag.

Do you have an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @cosiek That's weird because as from [AMP official documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/custom_fonts) it's valid syntax...

Comment: It says - "The following origins are allowlisted and allowed for font serving via link tags: https://use.fontawesome.com." You can try contacting the AMP developers on GitHub, I believe they will help.

Comment: Thank you. Will do that.